# GROUP BY / HAVING CLAUSE Failing in Sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

Inside a list, I have an item : shop.
Shop have the same id, but different group_id.
The primary key is shop_id, group_id

The first time I display the list, I want to group those 2 ( As it is the same shop)
In the next screen.

So, my query is :

```
SELECT  * FROM TABLE_SHOP  GROUP BY ID
```

But then, When I process it, I need to separate the shops with field "done" = 0/1

if done = 1, I will disable the element.

I tried to add a clause :

```
 SELECT  * FROM TABLE_SHOP GROUP BY ID HAVING DONE =0
```

But then, when one is done, the shop doesn't appear anymore in the list. ( instead of showing one disabled, and one enabled)

Any idea of what is failing in the list?

EDIT :

[image: table]

I changed fields name to match picture.
In this case, I want to display the list.
The first time I display it ( all done fields in 0), I want the shop 25975 ( 2 records ) appears just once ( that's why I used GROUP BY)

Then, when I process a shop, it will update his done field to 1.

So in this moment, I don't wan't to group anymore the 2 rows. It it clearer???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working.

The query was :

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_TIENDA WHERE TIENDA_DONE = 0 GROUP BY TIENDA_ID, DONE
```

Tx for your help

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of HAVING clause is to filter using aggregate functions. 
Try this instead:
SELECT  * FROM TABLE_TIENDA WHERE TIENDA_DONE = 0 GROUP BY TIENDA_ID

Comment: But here, I will not see the shop that have TIENDA_DONE = 1. I need to keep it in the list, so that I can't disable it

Comment: So, you want all shops to be visible? If so, what do you mean by "separate the shops"? If you want "done" shops to be separated from "undone" e.g. all "done" shops are an top of list, you can use ORDER BY clause:
SELECT  * FROM TABLE_TIENDA ORDER BY TIENDA_DONE, TIENDA_ID, GROUP_ID.

Comment: I want to group them first, when both tienda_done = 0.

Comment: Could you please provide an example with tables: what you have and what you want to get?